# Executing hazelcast task in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, hazelcast

I have task 'InfoTask' . When I tried to run it in local hazelcast it works

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance();
    IExecutorService executor = hazelcastInstance.getExecutorService("exec");
    for (int k = 1; k <= 1000; k++) {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        System.out.println("Producing echo task: " + k);
        Future<InfoHz> a = executor.submit(new InfoTask("a", "b", "c"));
        a.get();
    }
    System.out.println("EchoTaskMain finished!");
}
```

but when I tried to execute this in kubernetes with hazelcast in kubernetes I got `HazelcastSerializationException`

How should I fix this ?

```
com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.HazelcastSerializationException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: my.hazelcast.InfoTask
```

**UPDATE**

why there is no mention in hazelcast [doc](https://docs.hazelcast.com/imdg/4.2/computing/executor-service#latest-banner) about serialization of task ? How it can work and dont throw `HazelcastSerializationException` when they dont add jar in classpath ?

Answer (score 0):

The code that contains `my.hazelcast.InfoTask` needs to be on the classpath of the Hazelcast pod.

There are a number of ways to achieve this, depending on how you choose to deploy on Kubernetes.

Two ways, but there are others:

- Simple classpath :
  If you use something like [helm](https://github.com/hazelcast/charts/tree/master/stable/hazelcast) then the `volumeMounts` allows you to make a directory containing your code available. It's easier here to start with [Docker : extending-classpath-with-new-jars-or-files](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-docker#extending-classpath-with-new-jars-or-files) to get the concept working.
- Custom Jar : build your own image, using `jar-with-dependencies`, then it's just a single image for the pod, configuration and code can be baked in rather than external. [Here](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-code-samples/tree/master/hazelcast-integration/kubernetes/samples/springboot-k8s-hello-world/the-server)'s an example .

Comment: I saw your comment that it is possible to use Portable interface ? This will also solve my issue ? I want to avoid adding something to classpath. We solve this problem using codeDeployment but everytime you change task or classes inside Task you need to delete our cache